# Integrable of composion of functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $G : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $|G(t)|/|t|$ is not bounded.
Prove that there is a function f belong to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ (here we use lebesgue measure) such that $G\circ f$ is not belong to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$

Can any one give me some hints for this problem ?

Comment: I am trying to prove that such $f$ exists

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider these 2 cases:

1. $G(0)\neq 0$
2. $G(0)=0$

For the first case, finding such $f$ looks simple.
For the second case, note that $\frac{1}{x^r}$ is in $L^1([0,1])$ when $0<r<1$, and $\frac{1}{x^r}\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Is it correct if I set $f=\frac{1}{x^r}\chi_{[0,1]}$ ? Is that what you mean Nate?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Note that $\frac{1}{x^r}$ is in $L^1([0,1])$ implies $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: But i still do not know how to prove that $G(\frac{1}{x^r})$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: But you know that $G(t)/\vert t \vert$ is not bounded. Then, can you say $x^rG\left(\frac{1}{x^r}\right)$ is bounded as $x\rightarrow 0$? Then, what about $G\left(\frac{1}{x^r}\right)$?